# Getting my facebook friends IDs for javafx desktop application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, javafx

Developing a desktop application(javafx) where I need to retrive a list of my Facebook friends ID - what I know so it'is imposible to do by just sending ".../me/firends" (with version 2.3+) because that give me in responds just a number of friends.So I figure to use facebook friend selector to first send invite and in case of acceptance get user ID-but it seams like invites are only available for android and ios [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview) - any ideas how can I takle that issue?

Comment: `/me/friends` returns the friends that are also users of the app, and have granted `user_friends` permission as well. And that is what your app is supposed to make do with.

Comment: @CBroe but how can I send an invite to them from my app so that they can grantn user_friends permission..?To be clear:  I am making a "job scheduler" application so when the person get a shift they will be notified about it trough facebook (so tthat "friends" themselfs not gona use the application direcly)

Comment: Your alternatives for inviting for non-canvas/non-game apps are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_1291953124230220 // _“(so tthat "friends" themselfs not gona use the application direcly)”_ - well then why do you need access to them in the first place?